# Azure Service Principal pull images from Container Registry

Tags: azure, docker, azure-cli, azure-container-registry, service-principal

I have created a Azure Service Principal like this

`az ad sp create-for-rbac --name $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME --scopes $ACR_REGISTRY_ID --role reader`

after logging in (`az login --service-principal -u $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_NAME -p $SERVICE_PRINCIPAL_ID --tenant $TENANT_ID`) I am able to see all the images (`az acr repository list --name $ACR_REGISTRY_NAME`) which are in my registry, but I can not push or pull images (`docker pull myregistry.azurecr.io/myimage:latest`).

Are there any permissions I am not aware of? I have tried the similar with other roles like `owner` or `contributor`, but also SPs are getting the same error, which is the following:

> Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/myimage/latest/manifests/latest: unauthorized: authentication required

---

Update 14. of August:

I am also not able to docker login with the SP

> Error response from daemon: Get myregistry.azurecr.io/v2: unauthorized: authentication required

Comment: Looking your error seems you need to `docker login` first.

Comment: for docker login you have pass the service principle clientId and password and service principal should have acrpull permission.

Answer (score 4):

You need to login to the registry using docker login

`docker login myregistry.azurecr.io -u xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx -p myPassword`

Refer to: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-authentication#service-principal

Comment: Unfortunately that is not working either: > Error response from daemon: Get https://myregistry.azurecr.io/v2/: unauthorized: authentication required

Comment: you have to replace <myregistry.azurecr.io> with your login server

Answer (score 4):

For the Azure Container Registry, there are two ways to log in.

One is that log in with the command `az acr login -n azureacrServer -u username -p password`, you have the owner permission after logging in.

The other one is that log in with a service principal using the command `docker login azureacrServer -u servicePrincipalId -p sppassword`. In this way, you just have the permission of the service principal after logging in. I try and the result like the screenshot shows below:

[image]

This service principal is just set as a Reader. So we cannot push the image.

[image]

You can get the details about the service principal of Azure container registry with the command `az role assignment list --scope acrId`, the command will show all the service principals of the registry. The command `az acr show --resource-group groupName --name acrName --query id --output tsv` will show you the registry Id.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, the problem was actually in a completely different direction, for reference:  https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/2295

Comment: @zara So I suggest you get the information of service principal at the end of the answer.:-)